# Aviso: Intentando obtener propiedad de no objeto en public_html/index.php on line 23

Tags: php, html, mysql

Al querer iniciar sesión aparece un mensaje de error Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in

tengo un sistema web, en servidor local en el cual si puedo iniciar sesión, y cuando subí el sistema a Internet al querer iniciar sesión meda esta mensaje Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /storage/ssd1/717/8650717/public_html/index.php on line 23 y claro no puedo logearme a pesar que son correctas las credenciales

```
   ?php
        require("conexion/conexion.php");
        // Inicio de la sesión para su identificación
        session_start();
        if(isset($_SESSION['id_usuario'])){
            //en caso de que se detecte un inicio de sesión se redireccionará al menú del sistema
            header("location: extraescolares/home.php");
        }

        //modulo de inicio de sesión
        //en caso de que no se haya enviado nada con el metodo POST, no se realizará esta parte del código.
        if(!empty($_POST)){
            //se guardan los datos ingresados por el usuario en variables para su manipulación
            $usuario=mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST['usuario']);
            $password=mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST['password']);
            //$error='';
            //la contraseña se convierte en formato codificado sha1
            $sha1_pass=sha1($password);
            // se realiza la consulta a la BD con los datos ingresados
            $sql = "SELECT IdUsuario, IdTipo FROM Usuario WHERE Usuario = '$usuario' AND password='$sha1_pass'";
            //se obtienen los resultados de la consulta y cada uno de los campos
            $result = $conexion->query($sql); 
            $rows=$result->num_rows; //**<---------esta es la linea de error**
            // si los campos no estan vacios...
            if($rows >0){

                //se guardan los datos de usuario en la sesión actual y se redirecciona al menú del sistema
                $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
                $_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $row['IdUsuario'];
                $_SESSION['tipo_usuario'] = $row['IdTipo'];

                header ("location: extraescolares/home.php");
            }else{
                //$error = "El nombre o contrase&ntilde;a son incorrectos";
                //si los datos corroborados en la BD no existen, se redireccionará a la página principal sin acceso
                echo"<script>alert('El nombre de usuario o contraseña son incorrectos'); window.location.href=\"index.php\"</script>";
            }   }
    ?>
```

espero poder iniciar sesion

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que tu consulta no este produciendo un resultado ya sea porque no existe el registro o un error en el codigo sql que le estas enviando, por eso cuando intentas acceder a la propiedad num_rows se produce el error, en todo caso debes condicionar esto, esta es una forma:

```
<?php
        require("conexion/conexion.php");
        // Inicio de la sesión para su identificación
        session_start();
        if(isset($_SESSION['id_usuario'])){
            //en caso de que se detecte un inicio de sesión se redireccionará al menú del sistema
            header("location: extraescolares/home.php");
        }

        //modulo de inicio de sesión
        //en caso de que no se haya enviado nada con el metodo POST, no se realizará esta parte del código.
        if(!empty($_POST)){
            //se guardan los datos ingresados por el usuario en variables para su manipulación
            $usuario=mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST['usuario']);
            $password=mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST['password']);
            //$error='';
            //la contraseña se convierte en formato codificado sha1
            $sha1_pass=sha1($password);
            // se realiza la consulta a la BD con los datos ingresados
            $sql = "SELECT IdUsuario, IdTipo FROM Usuario WHERE Usuario = '$usuario' AND password='$sha1_pass'";
            //se obtienen los resultados de la consulta y cada uno de los campos
 //CONDICION PARA EL CASO DE QUE NO TRAIGA VALORES LA CONSULTA           
           if ($result = $conexion->query($sql)) {
               $rows=$result->num_rows; //**<---------esta es la linea de error**
               // si los campos no estan vacios...
               if($rows >0){

                //se guardan los datos de usuario en la sesión actual y se redirecciona al menú del sistema
                   $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
                   $_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $row['IdUsuario'];
                   $_SESSION['tipo_usuario'] = $row['IdTipo'];

                header ("location: extraescolares/home.php");
              }
            }
            }else{
                //$error = "El nombre o contrase&ntilde;a son incorrectos";
                //si los datos corroborados en la BD no existen, se redireccionará a la página principal sin acceso
                echo"<script>alert('El nombre de usuario o contraseña son incorrectos'); window.location.href=\"index.php\"</script>";
            }   
    ?>
```

Comment: hola ya lo condicione lo puse como el ejemplo y ahora carga la pagina dándome  el mensaje de usuario y contraseña incorrecta sin necesidad de escribirlo cheka el sig enlace https://extraescolar.000webhostapp.com